# Select one column as multiple column on other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm goin to start use mysql 5.1 community version.

First I have...

### master_product_table

```
ID  Product_Code    Product_Name           Product_Details 
=====================================================================
1   000001         Raw Material 1        000001- Raw Material 1
2   000002         Raw Material 2        000002- Raw Material 2
3   000003         Raw Material 3        000003- Raw Material 3
4   000004         Raw Material 4        000004- Raw Material 4
```

where `ID` field is the `PK`

### and master_document

```
Doc_no   Doc_date   Doc_type     Item_code1    Item_qty1     Item_price1     Item_code2     Item_qty2     Item_price2
=========================================================================================================================
000001   01-01-2013 BC. 2.3          1            200          $ 150             3             500           $800
000002   02-01-2013 BC. 2.7          2           1500          $ 800             4            6000          $2500
000003   03-01-2013 BC. 3.0          3           5000          $1500             1           12000          $8500
000004   04-01-2013 BC. 4.0          4          12000          $5000             2             750          $3000
```

where `Doc_no` field is the `PK`

What I want to get is like this...

```
Doc_no   Doc_date   Doc_type    Item_details1                Item_qty1    Item_price1       Item_details2                Item_qty2     Item_price2
========================================================================================================================================================
000001   01-01-2013 BC. 2.3    000001- Raw Material 1            200          $ 150       000003- Raw Material 3             500           $800
000002   02-01-2013 BC. 2.7    000002- Raw Material 2           1500          $ 800       000004- Raw Material 4            6000          $2500
000003   03-01-2013 BC. 3.0    000003- Raw Material 3           5000          $1500       000001- Raw Material 1           12000          $8500
000004   04-01-2013 BC. 4.0    000004- Raw Material 4          12000          $5000       000002- Raw Material 2             750          $3000
```

Any help on how to do this would be helpful thank you.

Comment: I would say your database schema isn't optimal (that's an understatement). I am not a DB expert, but I have seen many times that if you name columns with sequential numbers, that's a smell. And indeed, it makes the request more difficult than it needs (and I am not sure about the result data consistency...).

Comment: If you can, you should have a third table, Item (or similar), with id, qty, price, where you store your information and refer to it in master_document, or, better, via a relation table Doc_no <-> ID (with several IDs per Doc_no). It would be more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT md.Doc_no, md.Doc_date, md.Doc_type, 
       mp1.Product_Details Item_details1, md.Item_qty1, md.Item_price1, 
       mp2.Product_Details Item_details2, md.Item_qty2, md.Item_price2 
FROM master_document md 
INNER JOIN master_product_table mp1 ON md.Item_code1 = mp1.ID 
INNER JOIN master_product_table mp2 ON md.Item_code2 = mp2.ID ;
```

Comment: Aha! I hadn't thought of giving different names on the table depending on the join being made. Smart. Despite the question being too specific, I find the answer to be generally useful (for SQL newbies like me).

Comment: PS.: Do my comments above on splitting the table make sense, or is this an overkill in this simple case?

Comment: @echo_13 Do not forget to accept any one answer from all answers which is useful to you. You can accpet the answer by clicking on TRUE button at the left of answer. And you can accept only one answer

Comment: @Saharsh Shah Sorry before, and so many thanks for your wise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tried for first time **SQL FIDDLE**

Took approximately **30 mins**

Try the Following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbeef/6)

```
SELECT md.Doc_no, md.Doc_date, md.Doc_type, 
       pd1.Product_Details Item_details1, md.Item_qty1, md.Item_price1, 
       pd2.Product_Details Item_details2, md.Item_qty2, md.Item_price2 
FROM master_document md 
INNER JOIN master_product_table pd1 ON md.Item_code1 = pd1.ID 
INNER JOIN master_product_table pd2 ON md.Item_code2 = pd2.ID
order by md.Doc_no
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a quite basic question concerning SQL. Giving you a direct solution now will surely not help you in the future.

Try to get a smaller example and start learning how to use 'SELECT x FROM y WHERE x = w', as well as 
'SELECT x as z FROM y' (this renames the column x into z)

And then, if you get any more questions, add them here.

Have fun ;)